# D3.js Day Hour Heatmap dynamic update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, heatmap

I'm very new to D3.js and I'm trying to learn how to put things together correctly. I have a day/hour heatmap based on this example here: http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084

I'm trying to write an updateHeatMap method so that I can dynamically update the heatmap with new data. I've been researching and researching, and I honestly haven't found a successful solution. Any help would be appreciated, code snippets below

I have changed the original day/hour heatmap example slightly to look like this:

```
$scope.heatMapData = $http.get(...

$scope.initHeatMap = function() {

var margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30 },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 430 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24),
      legendElementWidth = gridSize*2,
      buckets = 9,
      colors = ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"], // alternatively colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9]
      days = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
      times = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a", "11a", "12a", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p", "12p"];



      $scope.colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
          .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max($scope.heatMapData, function (d) { return d.value; })])
          .range(colors);

      var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
          .data(days)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
            .attr("class", function (d, i) { return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis"); });

      var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
          .data(times)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .attr("y", 0)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
            .attr("class", function(d, i) { return ((i >= 7 && i <= 16) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis"); });

      var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
          .data($scope.heatMapData)
          .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.day - 1) * gridSize; })
          .attr("rx", 4)
          .attr("ry", 4)
          .attr("class", "hour bordered")
          .attr("width", gridSize)
          .attr("height", gridSize)
          .style("fill", colors[0]);

      heatMap.transition().duration(1000)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return $scope.colorScale(d.value); });

      heatMap.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.value; });

      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
          .data([0].concat($scope.colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; })
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend");

      legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
        .attr("height", gridSize / 2)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

      legend.append("text")
        .attr("class", "mono")
        .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height + gridSize);
  };
```

Here is what I have so far with the update method. This isn't working, because I'm not sure how to get the updated $scope.heatMapData into the new heatMap variable. I also need to update the legend to  match the new color scale, but that's second in priority under this.

```
$scope.rowSelected() = function(){
    $http.get(...).then(function(result){
        $scope.heatMapData = result.data;
        $scope.updateHeatMap();
    });
}

$scope.updateHeatMap = function(){
    var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

    var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
       .duration(250)
       .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.day - 1) * gridSize; })
          .attr("rx", 4)
          .attr("ry", 4)
          .attr("class", "hour bordered")
          .attr("width", gridSize)
          .attr("height", gridSize)
          .style("fill", colors[0]);

      heatMap.transition().duration(1000)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); }); 
}
```

Comment: I don't see you updating the data in `updateHeatMap`...

Comment: I updated it for you. The variable is being correctly updated, however I can't get the heatmap to update.

Comment: Yes, but you need to rebind `svg.selectAll(".hour").data($scope.heatMapData)`

Comment: I tried that to no effect, not sure where I went wrong. Right now my solution is to do this 'd3.select("#chart").selectAll("*").remove();' followed by another call to '$scope.initHeatMap()' - I know that this is incorrect, but nothing else is working...